# miserable-looking

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, conjunctions, hyphens

a. I saw a sick and miserable looking boy standing at the corner of the street.

b. I saw a sick and miserable-looking boy standing at the corner of the street.

The question is whether the boy was

1. miserable-looking and sick

or

2. sick-looking and miserable-looking

I think the hyphen in (b) might be considered an indication that 'looking' only modifies 'miserable'. But I think in practice such a 'rule' would not be considered a rule and one would have to rely on context to know what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Any time two or more words come together to describe a noun, it's considered a **compound adjective**.  Compound adjectives are often hyphenated. So there is a difference between:

> miserable-looking and sick  (miserable only describes looking, not sick)

and

> sick-looking and miserable  (sick only describes looking, not miserable)

A compound adjective isn't always created from two or more adjectives. It might be created using an adjective, a noun or an adverb and a participle.

Here's a [reference](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/compound-adjectives/) for you to become more familiar with compound adjectives.